# hibernate+java update taking more time

Tags: java, hibernate

```
dater.setBeat(new Beat());
datastore.save&update(dater);
```

hi.. i need to update only the beat obj into dater which is joined with dater, while inserting dater, time taken is too long cuz dater has many objects. Is there any way to optimise this? so that only beat obj has to be inserted not the entire dater obj..

Comment: This has nothing to do with Tapestry; it is strictly about Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can build up manually your Beat object: load dater linked to Beat from the database, let's call it daterDB. Then set it manually on Beat with beat.setDater(daterDB), it should be ok if dater has no changes of course. You should still be in Hibernate cache for the current session (level 1) so when you will update Beat, Hibernate should optimize the update as it already knows daterDB (which is attached to the session).